# Autotask Rest API Ticket Charge Status

Tags: api, rest

I am a software developer, currently creating an inventory system using the Autotask Rest API, I am currently developing a section that requires the ticket charge status to be changed, the status is read only and therefore I cannot change this in the Ticket Charge entity. I was wondering what the process is to achieve this, this is the make or break of the entire project so all help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the ticket charge status is read only, then I assume you will not be able to change it on the API. Have you considered storing the state on your own backend? A link to the API documentation would be useful.

Comment: @RalphKing Hi thanks for your reply, the status is read only as other processes are required in order for this field to be altered, for example in AutoTask if you POST to the InventoryItemReceiving entity this will create rows in several tables, including some tables that have read only attributes, my question is, which entity do i POST to in order for this action to happen regarding the ticket charges, this is the REST API Documentation (link to ticket charges): https://ww2.autotask.net/help/DeveloperHelp/Content/AdminSetup/2ExtensionsIntegrations/APIs/REST/Entities/TicketChargesEntity.htm